# Fetch post without refreshing - Vanilla JavaScript and Express.js

Tags: javascript, express, fetch

I'm making a Express.js app which has a form to send contact info to a mail address with a post function. I'm using a "front-end post" because if I do it entirely from the backend I need a route to go after the post.
I want to post the info without refreshing the page, but I can't make it.
My front-end code:

```
    formButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/contact', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            nombre: form.elements["nombre"].value,
            email: form.elements["email"].value,
            consulta: form.elements["consulta"].value
        }),
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(response=>{
            if(response.ok){
                return response.json;
            }
            throw new Error('Request failed');
        }, newtworkError => console.log(networkError.message)
    ).then(jsonResponse =>{
        console.log(jsonResponse);
    });
});
```

And the server side code to handle the request is:

```
app.post('/contact', (req,res)=>{
    sendMail(req.body.nombre, req.body.email, req.body.consulta);
});
```

The mail is sent with the sendMail function using nodemailer, and it works, but after execute the function the page refreshes and in the url bar appears the url "http://localhost:3000/?nombre=XXX&email=XXX%40XX&consulta=XX". 
How can I do the post without refreshing?

Comment: You aren't sending a response from back end  Also `response.json` is a function so should be `return response.json()`. Also need to prevent button default click action if it is type submit

Comment: I think chances are the button is in a form element and so the default behaviour is to refresh the page on clicking. You could prevent this by calling `event.preventDefault()` on the event which will be passed into your callback on the first line. Another possibility - or it could be both - is that you have an 'action' prop on the first element - this might explain why it's making a get request and why you're getting the query append to your url.

Comment: Thanks! event.preventDefault() works!